# Combine two PHP arrays; One as key and another as value

Tags: php, arrays

I have

Array **A**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1440:480
    [1] => thumb
    [2] => 240:auto
    [3] => small-thumb
    [4] => big-thumb
    [5] => detail-img
    [6] => tiny-thumb
)
```

Array **B**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1440x480
    [1] => 130xauto
    [2] => 240xauto
    [3] => 100xauto
    [4] => 150xauto
    [5] => 650xauto
    [6] => 45xauto
)
```

How to make this?

Array **C**

```
Array
(
    [1440:480] => 1440x480
    [thumb] => 130xauto
    [240:auto] => 240xauto
    [small-thumb] => 100xauto
    [big-thumb] => 150xauto
    [detail-img] => 650xauto
    [tiny-thumb] => 45xauto
)
```

Comment: Try array_combine http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php.

Comment: What he has done so fas is open a second second question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669406/please-help-me-about-php-array

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use [**array_combine()**](https://www.php.net/array_combine)

php.net example:

```
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr1 = array(0 => '1440:480',
    1 => 'thumb',
    2 => '240:auto',
    3 => 'small-thumb',
    4 => 'big-thumb',
    5 => 'detail-img',
    6 => 'tiny-thumb'
);

$arr2 = array
(
    0 => '1440x480',
    1 => '130xauto',
    2 => '240xauto',
    3 => '100xauto',
    4 => '150xauto',
    5 => '650xauto',
    6 => '45xauto'
);

foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
    $newArr[$val] = $arr2[$key];
}

print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(
    "1440:480",
    "thumb",
    "240:auto",
    "small-thumb",
    "big-thumb",
    "detail-img",
    "tiny-thumb"
);

$b = array(
    "1440x480",
    "130xauto",
    "240xauto",
    "100xauto",
    "150xauto",
    "650xauto",
    "45xauto"
);

function merge_arrays($keys, $values) {
   $merged = array();
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
     $merged[$keys[$i]] = $values[$i];
   }
   return $merged;
}

$c = merge_arrays($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most complicated of agorythms. Guessing both arrays have the same size as in the given example, you could iterate over the first and combine them using their identical IDs:

```
$c = array();
foreach($a as $id => $value){
    $c[$value] = $b[$id];
}
```